# Ingress does not creates route object in OpenShift 4.11

Tags: routes, openshift

I have a question regarding Openshift Ingress

According to this documentation
https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.7/networking/routes/route-configuration.html#nw-ingress-creating-a-route-via-an-ingress_route-configuration route should be created automatically to my service.
I did following
created new project:

```
oc new-project test-ingress
```

deployed dummy app:

```
oc new-app openshift/hello-openshift
```

and then created Ingress object (without TLS this time):

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: hello-openshift
spec:
  rules:
  - host: hello-openshift.mycluster.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          # Forward to a Service called 'hello-openshift'
          service:
            name: hello-openshift
            port:
              number: 8080
        path: /
        pathType: Exact
```

According to the documentation I should see automatically created route to my service.
But route was not created. Openshift cluster v4.11 in IBM Cloud.
Does anyone had same issue?

One NOTE: had same issue on older Openshift cluster v4.10 Cloud.
But when I changed from `pathType: Exact` to `pathType: Prefix` - route was generated. This not working with Openshift cluster v4.11. Any suggestions? Maybe there should be done some Ingress configuration that I don't know about?

Comment: Maybe you can find more information why the`Route`is not generated by checking logs of the `ingres-operator-xxx`pod in project `openshift-ingress-operator`

Comment: Checked pod ```ingres-operator-xxx``` in project ```openshift-ingress-operator```  - no error there or any records related to the issue. Strange

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tested on 4.12 I was able to create the route when I add ingressClassName while creating the ingress.

```
kind: Ingress
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: hello-openshift-class
  namespace: shashi-ingress
spec:
  ingressClassName: openshift-default   <<< 
  rules:
    - host: hello-openshift-class.apps.cs-ocp12.cp.fyre.abcd.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: hello-openshift
                port:
                  number: 8080
```

ingress with and without  ingressClassName defined

```
oc get ingress
NAME                      CLASS               HOSTS                                                 ADDRESS                                        PORTS   AGE
 
hello-openshift-class     openshift-default   hello-openshift-class.apps.cs-ocp12.cp.fyre.abcd.com   router-default.apps.cs-ocp12.cp.fyre.abcd.com   80      81m
hello-openshift-noclass   <none>              hello-openshif-nodefaultt.cs-ocp12.cp.fyre.abcd.com
```

route defined

```
oc get route
NAME                          HOST/PORT                                             PATH   SERVICES          PORT       TERMINATION   WILDCARD
hello-openshift-class-qcf4d   hello-openshift-class.apps.cs-ocp12.cp.fyre.abcd.com   /      hello-openshift   8080-tcp                 None
```

**Reference:**

OCP 4.12 security enhancement, you see alert: IngressWithoutClassName  for any existing ingress with no  ingressClassName defined

Following is the Enhancement details
https://github.com/openshift/enhancements/blob/master/enhancements/ingress/transition-ingress-from-beta-to-stable.md#implementation-details

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

There was a bug in 4.11 in IBM Cloud earlier. This version should fixed it: https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/openshift?topic=openshift-openshift_changelog_411#4118_1528_openshift

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I thought that this could be a bug. We have registered support case with IBM Cloud support. They are in investigation process at the moment. Waiting for their reply at the moment. As soon as we will have solution from them - i will post it here as well.

Answer (score 0):

routes backed by ingress are supported from openshift 4.11
create the ingress secret of the type tls(kubernetes.io/tls)
eg: kubectl create secret tls <secret_name> --cert=<test.crt> --key=<test.key>

and then provide this secret name in the tls section
Hopefully this works